# Why c++ allows to call grandparent class method directly from within child class?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance

Why C++ allows to call grandparent class method directly from within child   class. Doesn't that violate encapsulation? Language like Java doesn't allow to bypass parent class method means super.super.method() isn't allowed. But it is valid in C++. What is the reason? Consider following code.

```
#include <iostream>
class a1 
{
  public:
  void fun()
 {
    std::cout<<"fun() in a1\n";
 }
};

class a2 : public a1
{
   public:
   void fun() 
   {
       std::cout<<"fun() in a2\n";
   }
};

class a3 : public a2
{
   public:
   void fun()        // Bypass call to a2 class' method
   {
       a1::fun();
       std::cout<<"fun() in a3\n";
   }
};

int main()
{
     a3 a;
     a.fun();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because c++ doesnt care if you shoot yourself in the foot :)

Comment: `a1::fun()`, `a2::fun()` and `a3::fun()` are three separate fuctions, because neither of the first two are declared `virtual`. So don't think that each derived class is overriding the previous function. You are free to call any inherited functions that you want, which is often very useful.

Comment: Consider composition over inheritance, or private/protected inheritance

Comment: Why would it be forbidden? It's a public method. You could even call it from the outside through the base class pointer (missing a virtual keyword?)

Comment: @Cyber: Then why Java doesn't allow this?

Comment: because Java assumes you don't know how to program . C++ assumes you understand programs to the edge of bytes and RAM..

Comment: С++ allow multiple inheritance. Try create corrent syntax for this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked:

> Doesn't that violate encapsulation?

It does to an extent. Ideally, if `a3` needs to access any functionality from its ancestral classes, it should go through its direct base classes, i.e. parent classes. If the design changes and `a2` is not derived from `a1` any longer, the code in `a3::fun` will break.

You asked:

> What is the reason?

There is most likely a long list of reasons, too long to fit in an SO answer. I suspect the main reason is allowing the programmer the flexibility to do what makes sense to them.

Comment: @R Sahu: Thanks I am satisfied with your answer. But what do u mean by If the design changes and a2 is not derived from a1 any longer, the code in a3::fun will break? Thanks

Comment: @meet, during the life of a program, it is sometimes necessary to reorganize the class hierarchy. At a future date, it might make sense to make `a2` a sub-class of `foo`, which is not derived from `a1`. At that time, `a1` is not an ancestral class of `a3`. Hence, you cannot call `a1::fun()` from `a3::fun()`.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a base paradigm: "we are all educated grown-ups". In other words: the designers of the language understand that certain features might be misused; but they count on the sanity of the programmer to be careful.

In my opinion, it is very much the same with C++; its just not an "official mantra" as it is with python.